# Lo interface not coming up on boot (upgrade fom 12LTS to 14LTS, work in container mode)

Tags: boot, networking, 14.04, container

I am using the Linux container , I upgraded from 12LTS to 14LTS recently, however after upgrade, the lo interface cannot be start automatically,  and here is "ip link show"

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: ip6tnl0: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
5: ip6gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/gre6 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The state of lo is down by default , when `ifup lo` , it says `ifup: interface lo already configured`

I can only make lo workable if I type `ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0` up, but this is a manual way, I need it to come up automatically on boot, is there any clues to fix this? I had checked for long time and the configuration (/etc/network/interfaces, etc...) I have no idea now , please suggest some way for me to fix this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer, but I can give you a workaround.  Changing /etc/network/interfaces to treat the interface as static seems to do the trick:

```
auto lo
# iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet static
address 127.0.0.1
netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Yes, I know.  This is ugly.  It's wrong.  However it got me over the hump.  YMMV.

I got bitten by this after I removed NetworkManager from a clean install of 14.04.  Don't ask about nuking NM. :-(